# How does the code execution jump to the software interrupt handler?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, firmware

I am talking about a system which uses ARM cortex M3. The code which I am referring to is written in firmware. The user sends commands to do a particular job to the firmware and the firmware calls specific software interrupt handlers to do the task corresponding to the command being sent.I know that the software interrupt handlers are mentioned in interrupt vector table but how come the command issued by the user eg. erase will result in software interrupt being called inside firmware which will do the erase operation?

Comment: "The code which I am referring to is written in firmware" Is firmware a new programming language?

Comment: nonono, I was just saying it is a firmware code, u have a good sense of humour :D

Answer (score 0):

the software interrupt is an instruction (goes by other names too, same instruction).  The logic in the processor knows to then switch modes to supervisor or whatever is correct and begins execution (kinda like a jump) to the code indicated by the address in the vector table.  Then there is software there that handles the command, something you setup before calling the software interrupt instruction tells what is or what is effectively the operating system to do that system call for you.

The code at the application layer which makes a system call, the library/code that is linked into the application takes parameters from the application as well as sets up the appropriate information for the software interrupt, performs the software interrupt, gathers results when the interrupt returns and cleans up.

EDIT.

all of the vectors in the vector table work this way.  even reset.  the logic knows when an event has occurred, an interrupt, data abort, undefined instruction, etc.  the logic is hardwired to go to a specific address, read that value, which is an address, and then start executing at that handler address.  the swi/svc is just another "event" but one that we want to create directly vs creating an undefined instruction or an unaligned access, etc which all will do basically the same thing, trigger an event, normal execution stops, machine state may or may not be saved (some percentage is in an cortex-m3, but may depend on the event), and execution of the handler happens.  (in the m3 there isnt supervisor vs user that is full sized arm).  the svc/swi is one though that we want to create where undefined we could but dont normally want to.  hardware interrupts are not that much different, but we didnt insert an instruction to cause them, other logic causes them based on some event in that logic.  in all cases there is code that we (the programmers) have to write for each event we care to handle (well each that we need to handle, covering all the ones that might happen) one of which might be the svc/swi event and within that it is not defined by arm what you call the system functions or how they are defined.  arm may have a set they use, but you are technically free to create any mechanism you want and any set of system calls you want, you just have to make sure the caller and the callee agree on the definition and who is responsible for what.